# Crashing issue, might be due to a for loop

Tags: c

My program keeps crashing while I run it. I have isolated parts of it (using /**/) to try and figure out what the issue is, and I think it has something to do with the second for loop in my sort function, since isolating that prevents the crashing. However, I've tried fixing it in several different ways (using while/do loops instead, etc), but it manages to keep crashing. Ive also looked at the parameters and how I declared it in main, but I can't see an issue with that. Knowing me, its probably something really dumb ive been missing for hours trying to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 5

struct student
{
    char name[20];
    int hw1, hw2, hw3, ex1, ex2, totalhw, totalex;
    float classperc;
    char grade;
};


void student_info(struct student s[], int n, int *classex1, int *classex2, int *a, int *b, int *c, int *d, int *f)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\nPlease enter the student's name:\n");
        gets_s(s[i].name, 20);

        printf("\nPlease enter the student's homework grades:\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d", &(s[i].hw1), &(s[i].hw2), &(s[i].hw3));

        printf("\nPlease enter the student's exam scores:\n");
        scanf("%d %d", &(s[i].ex1), &(s[i].ex2));
        getchar();

        s[i].totalhw = s[i].hw1 + s[i].hw2 + s[i].hw3;  
        s[i].totalex = s[i].ex1 + s[i].ex2;

        *classex1 += s[i].ex1;
        *classex2 += s[i].ex2;

        s[i].classperc = ((float)s[i].totalhw / 1.875) + ((float)s[i].totalex / 3.333);

        if (s[i].classperc >= 90)
        {
            *a = *a + 1;
            s[i].grade = 'A';
        }

        else if (s[i].classperc >= 80)
        {
            *b = *b + 1;
            s[i].grade = 'B';
        }

        else if (s[i].classperc >= 70)
        {
            *c = *c + 1;
            s[i].grade = 'C';
        }

        else if (s[i].classperc >= 60)
        {
            *d = *d + 1;
            s[i].grade = 'D';
        }

        else
        {
            *f = *f + 1;
            s[i].grade = 'F';
        }
    }
}


void sort(struct student s[], int n)
{
    struct student temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j< SIZE; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(s[i].name, s[j].name) > 0)
            {
                temp = s[i];
                s[i] = s[j];
                s[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\nStudent: %s\nThe Three Homework Scores: %d %d %d\nThe Two Exam Scores: %d %d\n", s[i].name, s[i].hw1, s[i].hw2, s[i].hw3, s[i].ex1, s[i].ex2);
        printf("Total Homework Score: %d\nTotal Exam Score: %d\nClass Percentage: %f  Grade: %s", s[i].totalhw, s[i].totalex, s[i].classperc, s[i].grade); 
// It crashes right before executing this second printf statement (I have no idea why :[)
    }
}


void avg_exams(int classex1, int classex2, float *avgex1, float *avgex2)
{
    *avgex1 = classex1 / (float)5;
    *avgex2 = classex2 / (float)5;
}

void print_classinfo(float avgex1, float avgex2, int a, int b, int c, int d, int f)
{
    printf("\n\nThe Average Exam Score for Exam 1 is: %0.2f\nThe Average Exam Score for Exam 2 is: %0.2f\n", avgex1, avgex2);
    printf("There were %d A's, %d B's, %d C's, %d D's, %d F's in the class overall\n\n", a, b, c, d, f);
}

void main()
{
    struct student s[SIZE];
    int a, b, c, d, f , classex1, classex2;
    a = b = c = d = f = 0;
    classex1 = classex2 = 0;
    float classperc, avgex1, avgex2;

    student_info( s, SIZE, &classex1, &classex2, &a, &b, &c, &d, &f);
    sort(s, SIZE);

    avg_exams(classex1, classex2, &avgex1, &avgex2);
    print_classinfo(avgex1, avgex2, a, b, c, d, f);

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Read compiler warning one by one & start solving. `grade` is declared as `char` type, what should be format specifier for `s[i].grade` ? `%s`---> `%c`.

Comment: Grade is a char but you print it with format code `%s` rather than `%c`. It has nothing to do with your `for` loop. If you had compiled with warnings your compiler would have warned yoi about this error.

Comment: I guess I am an idiot, thanks friends!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out your `printf()` format codes.  You can break it into smaller chunks for debugging, to see which portion of the `printf()` is working unexpectedly.

I don't think the crash is due to your `for` loops.